# Using Base Class Method Value In Inherited Classes Overridden Method

Tags: java, inheritance

Base Class;

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Animal
{

    public void move()
    {
        int value = 0;
        System.out.println("Move");
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        value = rand.nextInt(2)+1;

    }

}
```

Inherited Class;

```
public class Cat extends Animal
{

    public void moveCat()
    {
        super.move();
        System.out.println("Move Cat");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cat test = new Cat();
        test.moveCat();
    }
}
```

I Am trying to use a value of the base class animals method move in the override method moveCat. Why cant I use the value "value" in moveCat from Cat.

For Example;

```
public void moveDoodle()
{
    super.move();
    System.out.println("Move Doodle");
    if(value == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Value from base");
    }

}
```

If I am grabbing the content from the base method why can't I also use the values. If its not possible what should I be doing instead in order to get the values I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `value` is in the local scope of the method `move()` of your base(`Animal`) class and that is why its not inherited. Only the instance variables will be inherited(provided they are not `private`). Thus, you need to make `value` an instance variable for you to be able to inherit it in your base(`Animal`) class.

```
int value = 0;
public void move()
{
    // int value = 0;
    System.out.println("Move");
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    value = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
}
```

*Note:* I can see that you've inherited the `Animal` class but have not overriden any method, contrary to what was suggested in the question title.

Comment: And for code readability, qualify all references with `this.`

Comment: Great, I have made it a class wide variable and uses this.value = value inside the method.

Comment: @user2998504 - Inside which method? I didn't quite get that.

Comment: I made sense to me though that you would be able to use it locally because are taking the methods local information with super.

Comment: @R.J forget that statment, I don't need this.value = value because there is no local value once I declare it globally.

Comment: @user2998504 - Yeah exactly. You don't need that and you can directly refer `value` in the `Cat` class's `moveDoodle()` method.

Answer (score 0):

because `value` is a local variable to method `move()`. Local variables are not inherited. Create the variable as instance variable. 
By the way, if you are trying to override to `move()` method, you need to keep the same method signature.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Animal {
    int value = 0;

    public void move() {

        System.out.println("Move");
        Random rand = new Random();
        value = rand.nextInt(2) + 1;

    }

}
```

Your Cat class

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public void moveCat() {
        super.move();
        System.out.println("Move Cat");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat test = new Cat();
        test.moveCat();
        System.out.println(test.value);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have changed the method name not signature.

Comment: I've updated my code so that value can be accessed in Cat class.

Answer (score 0):

With your implementation, the `value` variable is of local scope. It is accessible only within the `move` method and the outer world doesn't know about this.

You will need to declare this variable at the instance scope in order to make it accessible at the class level. You will also need to declare the access modifier for this so that the inheriting class know about it.

The following will work.

```
protected int value = 0;

public void move()
{
    System.out.println("Move");
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    value = rand.nextInt(2)+1;
}
```